# Using inner join and not in together in mysql

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a wordpress database with default users table and two custom tables as below

```
1. wp_users

| id | display_name |
|----|--------------|
|  1 |         Ibbs |
|  2 |         Nina |
|  3 |        rakib |


2. wp_invite

| post_id | user_id |   status |
|---------|---------|----------|
|    3342 |       1 | accepted |
|    3342 |       2 | accepted |
|    3342 |       3 | accepted |



3. wp_rating
| id | reviwer | reviewed | post | know | skill | time | comm |
|----|---------|----------|------|------|-------|------|------|
|  2 |       3 |        1 | 3342 |    b |     b |    b |    b |
|  5 |       1 |        2 | 2122 |    a |     c |    d |    a |
|  7 |       2 |        3 | 3342 |    d |     a |    b |    c |
```

i want to `select * from wp_invite where status = accepted`, `display_name` from `wp_users` and then want to exclude rows from the result where all of these three conditions meet
1.  `wp_invite.user_id` is not equal to `wp_rating.reviewer` and
2.  `wp_invite.user_id` is not equal to `wp_rating.reviewed` and
3.  `wp_invite.post_id` is not equal to `wp_rating.post`.

My desired output for `post = 3342` and `reviewer = 3`

```
| user_id | display_name |
|---------|--------------|
|       2 |         Nina |
|       3 |        rakib |
```

My desired output for `post = 3342` and `reviewer = 2`

```
| user_id | display_name |
|---------|--------------|
|  1      |         Ibbs |
|  2      |         Nina |
```

My desired output for `post = 2122` and `reviewer = 2`

```
| id | display_name |
|----|--------------|
|  1 |         Ibbs |
|  2 |         Nina |
|  3 |        rakib |
```

My desired output for `post = 2122` and `reviewer = 1`

```
| id | display_name |
|----|--------------|
|  1 |         Ibbs |
|  3 |        rakib |
```

I have tried the following query but my output is empty:

```
SELECT wp_invite.user_id, wp_users.display_name, wp_invite.post_id 
FROM wp_invite 
INNER JOIN wp_users ON wp_invite.user_id = wp_users.id 
WHERE (status = 'accepted') 
AND user_id NOT IN (SELECT reviewer FROM wp_rating) 
AND user_id NOT IN (SELECT reviewed FROM wp_rating)
AND post_id NOT IN (SELECT post FROM wp_rating)
```

Comment: When you say exclude, do you mean you want or do not want entries that meet the conditions?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @turtle tread do not want

Answer (score 0):

ID should be capitalized: 
   inner join wp_users on wp_invite.user_id = wp_users.**ID**

Comment: That's not the issue.

Comment: @rakibulmuhajir when doing join statements, you should always use the table name for the columns. Which status, post_id are you referring to is important. e.g. wp_invite.post_id